# Service which provides interface-impelementation instead of data

Tags: web-services, interface, servicestack

Since a while now I'm implementing services whenever possible with ServiceStack (or WebAPI) instead of WCF.

What I want to do now is sending an interface (-name) to the server and get a class-implementation back. Maybe that's confusing, so I'll give you an example:

My service-client has multiple operations - like "check form":
The logic for checking this form is not implemented. What it has is an interface called `IFormChecker` with methods like `NameIsValid(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName)`.

Instead of sending the whole form-data to the server for validation, the client will request the implementation of `IFormChecker` from the server.

I know that's possible with WCF, but I have no idea how to do that with ServiceStack.
If that's possible, what's the way to go? I checked the documentation, but I'm not really wiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like there's no "magic trick" or anything.
I have to serialize/deserialize the class "old-fashion way".

If you're interested, here's the solution:

I created a "Root"-Interface, in this example it is IModule.
This IModule contains only 1 property, called Name.
It is a string and only there for convenience:

The IFormChecker from the example would be derived from this interface:
My client knows the value of this Name-property and of course the interface itself.
It will now fire the Name-value to the server, which will return the serialized class.

All I have to do is:

```
var module = ModuleImplementations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
if(module == null) throw new SomeException();

return module.Serialize();
```

client-wise I can deserialize it and cast it to the interface. That's it.

Here's my ModuleSerialization-Class:

```
public static class ModuleSerialization
{
    public static string Serialize(this IModule m)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, m);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string serialized) where T : class, IModule
    {
        var ba = Convert.FromBase64String(serialized);

        using (var s = new MemoryStream(ba))
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            return bf.Deserialize(s) as T;
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!